# Type mismatch, expected ListBuffer[Any], actual ListBuffer[CustomClass]

Tags: scala, class, types, casting

I don't understand the title error knowing that for this function :

```
def myFunction(objectList: ListBuffer[Any], `object`: Any): Boolean = {...}
```

called with these parameters :

```
myFunction(
  objectList // :ListBuffer[CustomClass],
  customObject // :CustomObject
)
```

Am i obliged to call function like this :

```
myFunction(
  objectList.asInstanceOf[ListBuffer[Any]],
  customObject
)
```

Produces mismatch type error only for ListBuffer parameter.
So CustomObject => Any is ok but no ListBuffer[CustomObject] => ListBuffer[Any] ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Thats because `ListBuffer` is invariant so you can't assign `ListBuffer[A]` to `ListBuffer[SuperTypeOfA]`, the reason for that is `ListBuffer` is mutable which is unsafe to make `Covaraint`. https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/variances.html

Answer (score 0):

You are using parameter name object, which is a keyword in scala.

```
def myFunction(objectList: ListBuffer[Any], customObject: Any): Boolean = {...}
```

If you want object as parameter name, use tilt symbol before it.

```
def myFunction(objectList: ListBuffer[Any], `object`: Any): Boolean = {...}
```

Other problem is you can't make it Any using asInstanceOf. So, change ListBuffer[Any] to ListBuffer[CustomClass]

```
def myFunction(objectList: ListBuffer[CustomClass], customObject: Any): Boolean = {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mmm, so or this is not the good collection to use and there is a better either I use it badly and must not give it to the function but initialize into the function instead ?

I suppose Seq are covariant because defining function as following, this works :

```
def myFunction(objectList: Seq[Any], object: Any): Boolean = {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `CustomObject` and `CustomClass` are actually supposed to be the same (or `CustomObject` is a subtype of `CustomClass`), you may want to change the function to be generic:

```
def myFunction[A](objectList: ListBuffer[A], object: A) = ...
```

Otherwise, the issue is that `myFunction` can put anything into a `ListBuffer[Any]`, but if you pass a `ListBuffer[CustomClass]`, you can only put values of type `CustomClass` into it. This explains why `ListBuffer` is invariant.

If `myFunction` isn't going to put anything into the `Buffer`, you can just use `Seq` (or even more general types), which *is* covariant. You will be able to pass a `ListBuffer` there because it extends `Seq`. Generally, it's a good policy to give the most general possible type to method arguments.